# Python: Object initialised inside a Class?

Tags: object-oriented, python

Is possible and, if so, common practice to initialize an object inside a class in Python?

```
self.field = Class()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything in Python is an object, so yes, this is common practice. You could not create a meaningful Python program without creating other instances in your own classes.

Comment: Thank you Martinijn, I am new to Python and enjoying Oop !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in a Object Oriented way, you could pass a factory into the class, so that you can instantiate your class using a factory method:

```
    self.field = myFactory.GetSomeClass()
```